# Function of Pass through port on Access Point?

Tags: access-point

I have an Alcatel Access Point 1201H which has got 1 uplink gigabit port while 3 downlink ports. Also there are two ports named "PT" which mean pass through ports. I want to know what is this port used for?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The Pass Through (PT) port is used for giving access to another device without switching. A good example would be an analog telephone line. The port is active, even though the access point fails.

If there are two cables in a wall jack, one for providing connectivity to the Access Point and a second one for some other purpose and it needs to be guided out from behind the Access Point, the Passive Pass-Thru port on the AP can be used for this purpose.

The AP is designed for hotel rooms, dorms, classrooms etc.